# Method invoction 'actionBar.hide()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: android

when i run this program, always force stop, and show this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at top.riansaepuloh.carisewa.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:46)
```

this is code program DetailsActivity.java

```
package top.riansaepuloh.carisewa;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int ANIM_DURATION = 600;
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Setting details screen layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_view);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
```

the error always pointing to  `actionBar.hide();` 
how can solve this error ?

Comment: well obviously `getSupportActionBar()` returns `null`. Find out why is that.

Answer (score 0):

`actionBar.hide()` produces an error because `getSupportActionBar()` is returning `null` since it cannot find it.

Usually this is because the theme that you set is something like "....NoTitleBar", if that is the case simply change your theme.